# FFMPEG command runs forever even on using timelimit

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg

Mostly I use a java code to run FFMPEG bash commands for watermarking a logo on video. I am using the following FFmpeg command to overlay an image on video. I have observed that at times for some random videos, the process keeps on running even after the timelimit assigned to it expires. At times it's more than a day or couple of days until not directly killed using `kill -9 pid`:

> ffmpeg -timelimit 900 -y -i
>   input_video
>   -i logoImage -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2[even];[1:v][even]scale2ref=iw*0.25:(iw*0.25)*(0.46446702)[2nd][ref];[ref][2nd]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w):(main_h-overlay_h)"
>   -c:v libx264 -b:v 300K -crf 28 -preset slow outputVideo

But this command never completes even on using **`-timelimit`** flag at times for some videos.

I have observed that for such processes output from `ps aux|grep ffmpeg` yeilds in something like:

> ubuntu   16620  0.6  6.7 1595044 515392 ?      Sl   Dec20  12:05
>   ffmpeg -timelimit 900 -y -i
>   input_video
>   -i logoImage -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2[even];[1:v][even]scale2ref=iw*0.25:(iw*0.25)*(0.46446702)[2nd][ref];[ref][2nd]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w):(main_h-overlay_h)"
>   -c:v libx264 -b:v 300K -crf 28 -preset slow outputVideo

It indicates that this process is in interruptible sleep state i.e. waiting for an event to complete. On using `sudo strace -p 16620` to trace which system call is this process hung up on it results in something like:

> Process 16620 attached write(2, "frame= 4121 fps= 10 q=33.0 size="...,
>   99

i.e. it's stuck writing to a file.

What could be the reason for this problem? 
And is there any other way to kill FFMPEG process which overshoots desired time limit?

Comment: Possibly it's "stuck" writing its stderr to "your java process" are you reading both stdout and stderr *at the same time* while running the process?

Comment: Yes, I read first the stdout and then stderr for any bash process executed by "my java process".

Comment: @t6nand  You need to read both stdout and stderr *at the same time*. You can *not* read stdout first, and stderr later. The easiest way to do this is `ProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true)` to merge the two into a single stream

Comment: Okay, but it does work for many videos at first place. And regarding reading both streams *at the same time*, it might be debatable as I don't want to use `redirectErrorStream(true)` from `ProcessorBuilder` API, to distinguish from which stream I get data. Also if I run 2 concurrent java threads for reading from both streams it may result in swapped lines from both streams in the result.

Comment: That's why you're encouraged to post Qs that meet  [Minimal,Complete,Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines. As is, we have to guess what you are using and why it is failing. Please update your Q so readers can copy/paste code into their environment and see your problem and current solution. Good luck.

Comment: `timelimit` may not be available in your build. Check the full log from ffmpeg run and search for `timelimit`

Comment: There are ways to read from both and still distinguish them, not sure exactly which, good luck!